# Is there a way to batch edit start and stop times for events in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to know if it is possible to edit several events at once.  I have several **individual** events in my Google Calendar with the same name.  I would like to be able to change the start and/or stop times on all events that use the same title at the same time.

Also, I would like to be able to add the same description for several individual events at once.

I am willing to use a script to do this if someone could post one in the answer that I could copy and paste.